# Read more link returns blank page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a custom theme and I'm using a template for a blog page. In my template I have a code that calls specific posts according to category. So far so good, problem is when post contains "read more". Link is active but when I click on it I only get an empty page instead of an whole article.

This is my code:

```
<?php
        $args = array(
                   'category_name' => 'blog',
                   'post_type' => 'post',
                   'posts_per_page' => 10,
                   );

        query_posts($args);

          while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
              <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
              <?php echo '<p class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> ';
                    echo get_the_date();
                    echo '</p>';
                    echo '<h2>';
                    echo '<a class="permaLink" href="';
                    echo the_permalink();
                    echo'" title="';
                    echo the_title_attribute();
                    echo'">';
                    echo the_title();
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</h2>';
                    echo '<p class="posts">';
                    echo get_the_content('<br/><br/>Read more...');
                    echo '</p>';

                    echo '<hr/>'; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `empty page` as in the `It seems we can't find what you're looking for. Perhaps searching can help.` or everything on the page is white?

Comment: You need a singular page like single.php see what other options you have http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks Michal S, with single.php it works